# Android go trough all RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my app, the list item I'm displaying it is simple a **TextView inside a CardView**, when I click on any displayed TextView, it's gonna be my selected item I'll working with later.
Idea is, if I click to any of them, the CardView which holds it should change bgcolor, to for example color accent.

The problem is that once I change one of the cardview's bgcolor, then I don't know how should I do it back, when I click to any other TextView from the RecyclerView.
The code I'm working with:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

    int favIndex = copyDatas.get(position).fieldNames.indexOf("fav");
    boolean fav = (boolean) copyDatas.get(position).values.get(favIndex);
    if (fav) {
        holder.fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.notfav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.notfav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Choosen: " + mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String entity_name = mNames.get(position);                
            holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        }
    });       
}
```

So basicly what I wanna do is this: when I click on them (holder.name.setOnClickListener...) it should go over each RecyclerView item, and reset their bgcolor to primary color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember what position is selected. Then from there you can conditionally alter the background in onBindViewHolder

```
int selectedPosition = 0;

    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

    int favIndex = copyDatas.get(position).fieldNames.indexOf("fav");
    boolean fav = (boolean) copyDatas.get(position).values.get(favIndex);
    if (fav) {
        holder.fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.notfav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.notfav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

   if (position == selectedPosition){
     holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
   }
   else{
       holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getColor(R.color.otherColor));
   }

    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Choosen: " + mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String entity_name = mNames.get(position);                

            selectedPosition = position;
            getadapter().notifydatasetchanged();
        }
    });       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're updating items in a `RecyclerAdapter`, you should use one of the adapter's `notify` methods. In your case, you're keeping track of a selected item, when the user selects a new one, you only need to update the previously selected item.

If your `ViewHolder` is within your adapter, you can create a method and a variable to handle this pretty easily.

```
public class MyAdapter {

    // keeping track of the currently selected item
    private int selected = -1;

    public void updateSelectedItem(int position) {
        int previous = selected;
        selected = position;

        // tell the adapter to re-render the two positions to redraw their backgrounds
        notifyItemChanged(previous);
        notifyItemChanged(selected);
    }


    public class MyViewHolder {

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            if(selected == position) {
                // show a selected background
            } else {
                // show the normal background
            }

            holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // notify the adapter the selected item has changed.
                    updateSelectedItem(position);
                }
            });       
        }
    }

}
```